# How to get a Key from HashMap which corresponds to the max value?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have the following `TreeMap` with the given 2 values:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();

// 1 --> 3
// 2 --> 4
```

I want to get the key which has the max value. I get the max value via:

```
int max = map.values().stream().max(Integer::compare).get();

// 4
```

However, I cannot filter the map keys based on this max value. So, how can I get the key of the max value (2)? Or key of the given value in `TreeMap`? I used `TreeMap` instead of `HashMap` so that I can sort the map if needed (maybe not need).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I used `TreeMap` instead of `HashMap` so that I can sort the map if needed (maybe not need).

For that purpose, `HashMap` will suffice, you might replace `TreeMap` with a `HashMap` if you are not utilizing it for anything else. And moreover, `TreeMap` can't help with this task because maintains the order of entries based on ***keys***, not on values (your example is slightly misleading - *max value* is mapped to a *max key*, if you change it, `TreeMap` will no longer be helpful).

To solve this problem with Stream API, firstly, you need to create a stream over the ***entry set***, because you can't access a key when you have only a value.

Terminal operation `max()` returns an optional object that will hold entry (if result is present). Method `map()` invoked on an optional will transform `Optional<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>` into `Optional<Integer>`.

Method `orElseThrow()` in this case will be a better alternative to `get()`. Both will throw an exception if optional object will be empty. If according to your logic, value is guaranteed to be present it better specify explicitly with `orElseThrow()` that your intention is to throw an exception when result is not present, because this case is abnormal.

```
NavigableMap<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();

int maxKey = map.entrySet().stream()
        .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()) // Optional<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> - entry
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)            // Optional<Integer> - key
        .orElseThrow();
```

Since multiple keys could have the same value, it is possible that **max value** will be mapped to more than one key. In this case you might want to get a list of these keys:

```
NavigableMap<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();

int maxValue = map.entrySet().stream()
        .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .orElseThrow();    
    
List<Integer> maxValues = map.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() == maxValue)
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Sidenote**: when you are working with a `TreeMap` and don't expect that variable could be assigned with an unsorted implementation of the interface `Map`, then use interface `NavigableMap` as a type. It'll provide you access to such methods as `getFirstEntry()`, `getFirstKey()`, `higherEntry()`, etc. that will not be available with `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the proper key you can use this:

```
Optional<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>> entry = map.entrySet().stream().max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());
System.out.println(entry.get().getKey());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the proper interface, this is extremely easy.

```
NavigableMap<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
return map.lastEntry().getKey();
```

More importantly, this is much more efficient than using any Stream at all.